# Calling jquery extension without parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery extension written like this:

```
$.fn.GetBootstrapDeviceSize = function() {
var cMobileSize = $('#users-device-size').find('div:visible').first().attr('id');
return (cMobileSize === "xs" || cMobileSize === "sm");
```

}

For calling this I use:

```
$().GetBootstrapDeviceSize()
```

Is there a way to call this same function like this:

```
$.GetBootstrapDeviceSize()
```

Or perhaps even like this:

```
$.GetBootstrapDeviceSize
```

Comment: The extension should be added directly to `$` if it doesn't require a context object.

Comment: Why do you want to add this to jQuery? It's very page-specific, seems like it should just be a function in that page's script, not attached to jQuery.

Comment: Because I use all over my app, which is used on desctop and mobile devices. I need one function, created in my common javascript file.

Comment: You only need to use `$.fn.myFunction = function()` when you want to use it against a collection of jQuery objects, like `$("div.myDiv").myFunction()`.  You just don't need the `fn` bit of your assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to call this same function like this:
>
> ```
> $.GetBootstrapDeviceSize()
> ```

Yes, put it on `$`, not on `$.fn`:

```
    $.GetBootstrapDeviceSize = function() {
 // ^^
    var cMobileSize = $('#users-device-size').find('div:visible').first().attr('id');
    return (cMobileSize === "xs" || cMobileSize === "sm");
    }
```

> Or perhaps even like this:
>
> ```
> $.GetBootstrapDeviceSize
> ```

Yes, but it probably wouldn't be best practice. You'd do it by creating a *getter* for that property on `$`:

```
Object.defineProperty($, "GetBootstrapDeviceSize", {
    get: function() {
        var cMobileSize = $('#users-device-size').find('div:visible').first().attr('id');
        return (cMobileSize === "xs" || cMobileSize === "sm");
    }
});
```

Then accessing `$.GetBootstrapDeviceSize` would run the function and give you the return value. I'd probably just call it `BootstrapDeviceSize`, though, since you're accessing it as though it weren't a method, so a noun rather than a verb makes sense.

Comment: @FrenkyB - I backed off "very bad idea" and went with "probably wouldn't be best practice" when I realized the function doesn't have side-effects. I'd probably do it as a function, but if you do it as a getter, I'd drop the `Get` on the name. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think the question would be, what difference does it make to use $.GetBootstrapDeviceSize vs $.fn.GetBootstrapDeviceSize? Just curious!

Comment: @jeetaz - `$.fn` points to the object that is used as the prototype of all jQuery instances (objects created by `$()` and lots of its methods). If the function isn't instance-specific, it doesn't belong there.